# How do I change the highlight color of tab bar icons in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tabbar

I have made a tabbed tutorial project and I have noticed that the usual override in [user defined runtime attributes: tintColor:Color:...] no longer seems to do the trick. What is the best way to work around this problem - I am prepared to do this programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Since there is currently no "Xcode 10", do you mean Xcode 8 and/or iOS 10?

Comment: It was a late night -.- and yes, Xcode 8 iOS 10 - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go the Main.Storyboard file in your Xcode project. Select your Tab Bar Controller. From the Document Outline, select the `Tab Bar`.

[image]

2. From the `Attributes Inspector` search for the field named `Image Tint`.

[image]

You can set it to any colour you want and that's it. Your tab bar items tint will be changed.

[image]

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Works like a gem. Thank you very much.